# Grails/Gorm : Sorting hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class that has a 'hasMany' relationship that I would like to sort on so results are consistent when retrieving.  Below is an example of the domain class.

```
class Author {

    static hasMany = [ books: Book ]

    static mapping = {
        books sort: 'title', order: 'asc'
    }
}
```

This produces the following error.

> Default sort for associations [Author->books] are not supported with
>   unidirectional one to many relationships.

How can I sort on title in this example?

I have been able to achieve sorting on another hasMany relationship.  Any feedback would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As  the error suggests you need to make  the relationship bidirectional for default order to work,

just add the following in `Book` domain

`static belongsTo = [author:Author]`  if you need default sort order to work.

Comment: Is there another option?  The code above is a simplified example and am unable to add the belongsTo declaration.

Comment: Are you adding belongs to Books?

Comment: I also can't use belongsTo in a unidirectional relationship. I use a domain called Messages that is used in multipe tables, therefore belongsTo cannot be used. It all works correct except for the default sorting in Messages based on a field with descending order

Answer (score 0):

Check if it will work for you

```
class Author {
    SortedSet books  // add this to your Author domain

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
} 

class Book implements Comparable {
    String title

    int compareTo(obj) {
        title.compareTo(obj.title)
    }
}
```